# insert each xml node to sql server 2008 table

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm having xml as shown below :

```
<Production>
  <AIS_ID>ais150Dz</AIS_ID>
  <WorkedOn>12-12-2017</WorkedOn>
  <Status>Completed</Status>
</Production>
```

I want to insert this into table as shown below

```
ID   Field_Ident   Value_Ident
1     AIS_ID        ais150Dz
2     WorkedOn      12-12-2017
3     Status        Completed
```

I found suggestions to do this,but in that i have to manually declare column names while inserting the data e.g. "/Production/AIS_ID". I want to make it dynamic, that is regardless of how many nodes in XML. The reason is, returned xml is not fixed.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Why do that in the first place? SQL Server has an `xml` type.

Comment: I have got the data in form of dictionary. To insert all the values in Database, i have to use for loop in C#. To avoid that, i have converted dictionary to xml string and i'm passing it to stored procedure. Now i want to insert each node and its value as shown in question.

Comment: You can use make a data context in the VS project which you can then take the datatable and save into the database.  The datacontext create the classes and mappings interface between c# classes and SQL tables automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML;

SET @XML = '<Production>
  <AIS_ID>ais150Dz</AIS_ID>
  <WorkedOn>12-12-2017</WorkedOn>
  <Status>Completed</Status>
</Production>'

SELECT  T.c.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(50)')
       ,T.c.value('(./node())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM @XML.nodes('Production/*')T(c);
```

[image]